# Installer hangs for ages then crashes just before the end of the installation process

Tags: 11.10, installation, live-environment

I am trying to install 11.10 on an Acer Aspire 5532, Windows 7 is already on the machine and I want to dual boot with Ubuntu (with view to installing some other flavors of linux in other partitions later).

Five times now the installation has failed in the same place, three from a DVD which came with a magazine and twice from a USB drive containing the image from the ubuntu site and prepared with Universal USB Installer (so two different sources) Im not sure weather it should matter what kind of partition i am trying to install to but I have tried using extended, logical and plain unallocated space and the same problem each time.

Also I have tried installing both from within the live environment and from boot time. Any ideas what is wrong? Thanks in advance!

PS Although no expert I have installed Linux on a number of machines over the years and was feeling reasonably confident until now. I am currently just wanting to upgrade from 11.04 to 11.10

Answer (score 2):

**SOLVED** - Resolved this issue by unchecking 'install this third party software'.('Download updates while installing' was already unchecked and the machine was offline) You can install mp3 codecs and flash player manually later. Hope this helps somebody.