# Installation of Ubuntu 11.10 crashes

Tags: system-installation

the installation of Ubuntu 11.10 crashed before being completed. The issue seems to be known and there was also a bug description displayed. I gathered from this bug discription that the problem is not yet solved (I downloaded the iso yesterday). Am I right?

I then tried to download Version 10.04 LTS 34bit instead (from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download). However, this was not possible either "could not read source file". The download was not completed.

Can anyone tell me which version does not have an installation bug and where I can download it??!!

Thanks.  Kind regards.

Comment: I've installed 11.10 a few times and it never crashed. Can you post a link to that bug report.

Comment: After unchecking "Download updates during installation" and "Install third party software" the installation worked fine ... there seem to be problems with these options. But for me everything is all right now. 

Unfortunately, I didn't keep the link to the bug report, so I can't post it! Sorry.

See also

http://askubuntu.com/questions/78624/installer-hangs-for-ages-then-crashes-just-before-the-end-of-the-installation-pr

Regards

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).